# Sharing a folder on Mac using command in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, file-sharing

Is there a way I can share a folder and assign permissions on Mac using commands in terminal, like we use the `netshare` and `calcs` commands in windows?

Answer (score 10):

Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) added several command line tools, including `sharing`. To share a folder:

```
sharing -a ~/Documents/Public
```

Its man page and [this article on the Apple.StackExchange blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/interesting-new-unix-commandsbinaries-in-os-x-mountain-lion/#sharing--createsharepointsforafpftpandsmbservices) explain how to use it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://systemsboy.com/2008/03/netboot-part-4.html), it should give you an idea on how to use `dscl` to create a new SharePoint entry. Afterwards you´ll then want to use `chmod` to set permissions to `rwxr-xr-x` and add ACLs that deny members of group `everyone` to delete the SharePoint.